# What's the best way to log an on going widget in handset?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget which mainly used to display date and month. However, after a few day the widget stop updating itself and must be replace in order for it to work again. Since I can't test its behavior in the emulator, I'd like to know if there's a best way to keep my application log separately and have it available to take a look later?

Also is it possible to updating the widget based on the system time. Right now I updated my widget every minute. But since its only displaying date and day, I just want to know if it's possible to trigger some event when the day changes?

Comment: A widget that updates every minute?  With AlarmManager?  I know this isn't an answer to your question, but that is probably terrible for battery life.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Since I haven't found a better way to do it yet so it stays as is for now. I don't plan on having the final version update every minute though, at worst it will be five or more minutes between each interval.

Comment: Have you looked into using `android:updatePeriodMillis` instead of `AlarmManager`? Only useful for intervals >30 minutes though, so if you're doing a simple date/time widget, you'll have discrepancies around midnight.

Comment: @Roman Nurik, I tried the updatePeriodMillis (actually I'm using it right now). Maybe I should switch to AlarmManager and set it to goes off just after midnight?